# Converting a tabitem to a window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, tabitem

Suppose I have a `TabControl` with some `TabItem`s, each tab Item contains a `UserControl`.

Is there a way to convert the `TabItem` to a window when its dragged outside the application window and vice versa?

Just like google chrome except that the window will only contain what was inside the `TabItem`.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an MVVM pattern, you should be able to do this:

When you drag the tab item out of the tab control, send a command to the VM to which creates a new window, passes the original datasource from the view (the tab item) to the window, then remove the tab item from its parent (the tab control) via a command to the parent VM.

Comment: it worked just fine!, but having problem doing the opposite! MVVM makes things really easy except for the fact that i have to use drag and drop events